# discord.js finding amount of reactions (server emojis)

Tags: discord.js

So im creating a bot for my discord server
it needs to check when there are x amount of upvotes
on a message and than do something

And i can't find a way to check amount of
server emoji reactions on a message

i only found how to check normal emojis

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question, provide some code and tell us what you've tried already? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(
 (emoji) => emoji.name === 'Potato'
);

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
 return reaction.emoji.name === reactionEmoji;
};

message
 .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
 .then((collected) => console.log(collected.size))
 .catch((collected) => {
  console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
 });

message.react(reactionEmoji);
```

Source: [discord.js doc](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector)

Comment: but i need to save the amount in a variable and to use a emoji that is only in the server

Comment: What do you mean with server-emoji?

Comment: the ones you can add in the server settings -> emoji

Comment: i used this to react with them                                                                                         const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'Potato');
message.react(reactionEmoji);

Comment: It also works with server-emojis and the reaction object has a count field.

Comment: so i do reactionEmoji.count?

Comment: No thats just your emoji string. You need the reaction listener `message.awaitReactions().then()`. I edited my answer.